# RSA OAEP Implementation compiling problem

Tags: c, linux, gcc, rsa, oaep

I downloaded RSA-OAEP example from https://github.com/Rupan/rsa. Next I compile in linux kali:

```
gcc -O0 -ggdb -Wall -W -DTEST tiger.o sboxes.o oaep.c -o oaep && ./oaep SomeRandomString
```

Output of this was:

> gcc: error: tiger.o: No such file or directory , gcc: error: sboxes.o: No such file or directory.

I compile this files using:

```
gcc -c sboxes.c and gcc -c tiger.c
```

Next i compiled

```
gcc -O0 -ggdb -Wall -W -DTEST tiger.o sboxes.o oaep.c -o oaep && ./oaep SomeRandomString
```

and it doesnt work output is wrong can you help me ?

Comment: you should use the same compiler flags for all of the .c files

Comment: OK. I solved this i use another hash function SHA-1, Thank you for your response :)